# Node Reference input with HTML preview

Tags: 7, views, nodes, ajax

I am trying to show a multiple node reference input control that shows the title and an image of each node.

I have achieved it using Autocomplete Deluxe but it allows users to create new objects in the control itself which I cannot allow. I have also tried Chosen with a reference view but it strips all HTML before showing in the list.

Are there any other modules or techniques I could try to achieve this?

Comment: Which Drupal version are you working with?

Comment: @ermannob, Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion that is the case for a View. You should prepare a view with the fields you want to display from referenced nodes.

Then install [Entity Reference View Widget](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) module. With that module you will be able to use your view to select the node references.

Comment: This isn't working for me. It's almost there but it won't allow me to add an exposed filter that submits on 'keyup' so to allow for autocomplete I need to add an 'apply' button.